# Target substitution in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a typical regression, there is a CATEGORY which is "basic" and a test-case "abc.c". To run a test "abc" in category "basic", the user has to key in:

```
    make basic_abc
```

Then the command should be:

```
    basic_abc: abc.c
        gcc -g -o abc abc.c
```

How can I write a rule, that WILL CHOP "basic_" in my $@. So that I can use the rule for all tests. **In pseudo language, how can I get the above rule with pattern substitution**

```
    basic_abc: $(patsubst .*_, " ", $@).c
        gcc -g -o  $(patsubst .*_, " ", $@)    $(patsubst .*_, " ", $@).c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
.PHONY: basic_%
basic_%: %.c
        gcc -g -o $* $<
```

Make already knows how to compile a .c file, though. From your question it would seem to make more sense for `basic_x` to depend on the compiled `x`, and run it on a bunch of test cases in the recipe, but maybe I misunderstand your setup.

Comment: I think this works. I will try it out. But why do we require .PHONY ?

Comment: The .PHONY target specifies that there is no build artefact (target file) with this name; it's just a "human" target whose actions should be repeated every time a make is requested (even if a file with this name exists and is newer than its dependencies, at least in theory).